# Как достучаться до переменной в запускаемом скрипте через crontab?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, sh, crontab

Делаю скрипт для backup'a баз. И не получается, чтобы файлы sql ложились рядом в текущую папку. Как это можно реализовать без абсолютных путей?

```
#!/bin/bash
current_dir=$(pwd)
mysqldump -u***** -p***** --databases db_name > $current_dir/db_name/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").sql
```

При запуске через crontab пишет Unknown command current_dir Как быть?

Comment: что именно у вас не работает? чего именно вы хотите добиться, присваивая переменной `PATH` значения, не являющиеся каталогами?

Comment: Я думал, что sh и bash — это среды выполнения. Мне уже подсказали, что pwd не будет работать из crontab.

Comment: это не «среды». bash — это программа. sh — это символическая ссылка (впрочем, тоже на программу). [`PATH` — переменная окружения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F)). pwd — внутренняя команда оболочки. естественно, она работает. так что у вас **не** работает?

Comment: Сообщение на внутреннюю почту `unknown command current_dir`

Comment: А как тогда можно сделать, чтоб например файлы ложились в папку рядом со скриптом?

Comment: вероятно, вы привели не весь код. приведённый код, будучи исполнен любой программой, выполняющей роль posix-совместимой оболочки, не может привести к такому результату. // *А как тогда можно сделать, чтоб например файлы ложились в папку рядом со скриптом?* — зависит от того, как именно вы вызываете этот скрипт. но вопрос у вас совершенно о другом. либо переформулируйте, либо удалите его вовсе.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53342/discussion-between--and-alexander-barakin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

из комментариев стало понятно, что под «текущим каталогом» автор подразумевает каталог, в котором находится сам скрипт.

обычно путь к скрипту оболочки (содержащий и имя самого скрипта) передаётся самому скрипту в виде «нулевого» параметра: `$0`.

извлечь из него путь к каталогу, т.е. отбросить имя файла (со скриптом), проще всего с помощью программы `dirname` (кавычки стоит употребить на случай наличия в `$0` спец-символов типа пробела):

```
current_dir=$(dirname "$0)
```

в принципе, этого уже достаточно для адресации каталога, но на случай, если скрипт запущен с указанием относительного пути (например, `./скрипт`), а требуется получить путь абсолютный, можно воспользоваться программой `realpath`:

```
 abs_path=$(realpath "$(dirname "$0")")
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246128/556876) получить путь к исполняемому скрипту:

```
current_dir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
```